# How to prevent text in a table cell from wrapping

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how I can prevent the text in a table cell from wrapping?  This is for the header of a table, and the heading is a lot longer than the data under it, but I need it to display on only one line.  It is okay if the column is very wide.

The HTML of my (simplified) table looks like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>Really long column heading</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Really long column heading</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Really long column heading</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Really long column heading</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Really long column heading</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Really long column heading</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>Really long column heading</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>data</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>data</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>data</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>data</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>data</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>data</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>data</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The heading itself is wrapped in a div inside the `th` tag for reasons pertaining to the javascript on the page.

The table is coming out with the headings wrapping onto multiple lines.  This seems to only happen when the table is sufficiently wide, as the browser is trying to avoid horizontal scrolling.  In my case, though, I want horizontal scrolling.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 632, accepted):

Have a look at the [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop) property, used like this:

```css
th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will force the contents of `<th>` to display on one line.

From linked page, here are the various options for `white-space`:

> **normal**
>   This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space, and break lines as necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> **pre**
>   This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.
>
> **nowrap**
>   This value collapses white space as for 'normal', but suppresses line breaks within text.
>
> **pre-wrap**
>   This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> **pre-line**
>   This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space. Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Comment: doesnt work for input field and button in same cell. randomly places below.

Comment: `Table` element must have `table-layout:fixed;` in order for this to work.

Comment: @Doomsknight Did you find a way to achieve it with an input field and another element in the same cell?

Comment: white-space: pre; was what I needed as -28.04 was wrapping between the - and 28.04

Comment: @Doomsknight I had the same issue with a checkbox and resolved it by updating the CSS with `input { display: inline; }`

Comment: it mess up the other cells, needs further fixing, i believe its incomplete solution as some other cells start overwriting

Answer (score 81):

```
<th nowrap="nowrap">
```

or

```
<th style="white-space:nowrap;">
```

or

```
<th class="nowrap">
<style type="text/css">
.nowrap { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>
```

Comment: Note that `nowrap` has been deprecated. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6 . Use style sheets instead.

Comment: **Note.** if used carelessly, this attribute may result in excessively wide cells.

Comment: @wisbucky How does one "use style sheets"?

Comment: @rogerdpack I believe they might be referring to setting `white-space` to `nowrap` using the `style` attribute, you can use stylesheets by either setting the attribute inline, defining the stylesheet in the html itself, or defining the style in an external document as explained by this article <https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp>

Comment: @rogerdpack: what @wisbucky said applies only to the first example. `nowrap` *attribute* is deprecated and you should use css (or style) `whitespace: nowrap` instead

Answer (score 26):

There are at least two ways to do it:

Use nowrap attribute inside the "td" tag:

```
<th nowrap="nowrap">Really long column heading</th>
```

Use non-breakable spaces between your words:

```
<th>Really&nbsp;long&nbsp;column&nbsp;heading</th>
```

Comment: Note that `nowrap` has been deprecated. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6 . Use style sheets instead.

Answer (score 14):

I came to this question needing to prevent text wrapping at the hyphen.

This is how I did it:

```
<td><nobr>Table Text</nobr></td>
```

Reference:

[How to prevent line break at hyphens in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753296/how-to-prevent-line-break-at-hyphens-on-all-browsers)

https://caniuse.com/?search=nobr

Comment: It is worth noting that the `nobr` tag is non-standard, as pointed out in the accepted answer linked in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755071/4257

Comment: Quite right. Your point is well received. I read all those comments, noted the experience of the corresponding commenters, and made a judgment call. The hyphen is a bit tricky. (Note: the question you linked in your comment is the same one I linked in my answer)

Comment: Yeah, it was meant to be the same question. I just wanted to be sure the caveat was posted here in case someone found this answer in the future, and didn't bother to read the linked reference.

Comment: Wow--weird one; thank you--I had the same issue with a date breaking to a newline after a hyphen

Answer (score -1):

#### For Use with React / Material UI

In case you're here wondering how this works for Material UI when building in React, here's how you add this to your `<TableHead>` Component:

```
<TableHead style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>
```