# How (where) can i set fixed cell size in nested html tables, with css?

Tags: html, css

There is a bunch of answer on how to set fixed cell sizes here, but I am having trouble finding where in my nested table hierarchy the parameters belong. My table is a visualization of a calendar, with display of possible multiple events. It shows half a year.

My html structure simplified, looks like this:

```
<table> (whole calendar)
  <tr> (whole row of days)
    <td> (a single day)
      <table> (to be able to display the different data of a single day)
        <tr>
          <td> (displays the weekday name)
          <td> (displays the day of month value)
          <td> (cell to hold single or multiple events)
            <table> (to be able to split up events inside the <td>)
              <tr>
                for each event, through jstl:
                <td> (display of a single event)
                in some cases the event <td> contains both a polygon shape, and text.
```

The output with to long strings/events looks like this:
[image]

Notice the line-break when the polygon and the text extends their given space. I love that they do not expand horizontally, but they should not expand vertically either.
it should look like this, only with cut strings if they extend their given space

[image]

I have tried to set max-height: on various components, both far up and far down in my hierarchy, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I have also experimented with table-layout: fixed; but this also makes absolutely no noticable change. As far as I can tell, there are aproximately 8-9 levels in my tables that could be the right place to set the fixed height I am looking for. The highest being the very first tr-level, and the lowest being the td that holds a single event.

1. Do I need to declare max-height and/or fixed table-layout on all
   levels of the hierarchy?
2. Are these the right parameters to use?
3. Is there a golden rule of precedence when using CSS to style nested
   tables (or other components)?

I would also welcome any tips on my choice of architecture. I have a feeling there are better ways to do it, but for now, my main goal is to make it work, and hopefully I'll get a little wiser every time.

**EDIT:**
according to the answer to [this questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300220/how-to-prevent-text-in-a-table-cell-from-wrapping?rq=1), I set the white-space: nowrap; on my top table element, and it worked almost as i wanted it. The cells are staying at their fixed height and width, but a little glitch is that the text continues to be displayed outside of it's to small cell.

Comment: I think add one more child element like P or div, and give fix width to that element

Comment: Might work. Where in the hierarchy exactly do you suggest I try this?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean whichever <td> then, as there are several

Comment: yea exactly I mean same

Comment: It worked, in a way, but nothing I can use unfortunately. It created various sized spaces (1-3 pixels) inbetween the separate cells containing the whole days. Also, even though the height of the colored <td>'s did shrink to it's supposed size, the text remains under the polygon, and is displayed overlapping the cell below...

Comment: Have you tried to set the CSS rule `overflow: hidden;` on the text that is inside the `<td>` tags? This should prevent the text from displaying outside its element container.

Comment: That worked. white-space: nowrap; in table scope, and overflow: hidden; in cell-scope, did the trick.

Comment: Why don't you post the answer to the question if that is working? XD

Comment: text-overflow, white-space and overflow should do when table has a fixed table-layout : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FkcJz is this what you try to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text should be cutted on the edge of the table cell you have to change the table-layout to fixed and the td needs a hidden overflow.

```
table{table-layout:fixed}
table td{overflow:hidden}
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td) might help as well.