# How to position all elements of Table Header in one line using React Table

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, styled-components, react-table

In the project we use React Table to render table data. I need to fix a bug and need to achieve the result that all elements in React Table column header are in one line. So far title and arrow for sorting are in one line, but filtering icon is below
[image]

This is how current code looks like

```
<StyledTableHeader
    key={idx}
    isSorted={column.isSorted}
    key={column.id}
>
    <span
        {...column.getHeaderProps(
            column.getSortByToggleProps(),
            {
                className:
                    column.collapse
                        ? 'collapse'
                        : '',
            }
        )}
    >
        {column.render('Header')}
    </span>
    <span>
        {column.isSorted ? (
            column.isSortedDesc ? (
                <StyledArrowDownwardIcon />
            ) : (
                <StyledArrowUpwardIcon />
            )
        ) : (
            ''
        )}
    </span>
    {columnsCount > 5 ? (
        <StyledHeaderDivFlex>
            {column.canFilter
                ? column.render(
                      'Filter'
                  )
                : null}
        </StyledHeaderDivFlex>
    ) : (
        <StyledHeaderDivBlock>
            {column.canFilter
                ? column.render(
                      'Filter'
                  )
                : null}
        </StyledHeaderDivBlock>
    )}
 
</StyledTableHeader>
```

when I wrap all elements of header into div and give props to have flex-direction row it partly works. You can see in the picture below that filtering icon actually goes inline with header, but sorting icon disappears. When I press on the header it only changes color to orange and I can see that sorting works, but it does not display sorting icon.

```
<StyledTableHeader
    key={idx}
    isSorted={column.isSorted}
    key={column.id}
>
    <div
        style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'row',
        }}
    >
    <span
        {...column.getHeaderProps(
            column.getSortByToggleProps(),
            {
                className:
                    column.collapse
                        ? 'collapse'
                        : '',
            }
        )}
    >
        {column.render('Header')}
    </span>
    <span>
        {column.isSorted ? (
            column.isSortedDesc ? (
                <StyledArrowDownwardIcon />
            ) : (
                <StyledArrowUpwardIcon />
            )
        ) : (
            ''
        )}
    </span>
    {columnsCount > 5 ? (
        <StyledHeaderDivFlex>
            {column.canFilter
                ? column.render(
                      'Filter'
                  )
                : null}
        </StyledHeaderDivFlex>
    ) : (
        <StyledHeaderDivBlock>
            {column.canFilter
                ? column.render(
                      'Filter'
                  )
                : null}
        </StyledHeaderDivBlock>
    )}
    </div>
</StyledTableHeader>
```

[image]

I have tried also to give to  display:flex; flex-direction:row, but it then goes crazy and it gives this propertly to parent for all headers, not touching single column header.

Can You please advise how I can fix it ?

thanks !!!!

Comment: I would go for css grid to place elements on certain positions

Comment: why You think using css grid might change the behaviour and could ring back the arrow of sorting which got lost ? Can You elaborate a bit around this ?

Comment: I have just used css grid and behaviour is the same

Comment: how did you use it?

Comment: from the code above I replaced :
<div
        style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'row',
        }}
    >
I made:
<div
        style={{
            display: 'grid',
            gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr 1fr',
        }}
    >

Comment: Try [styling it with the white-space property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300220/how-to-prevent-text-in-a-table-cell-from-wrapping#300237).

Comment: unfortunately it didn't bring expected result. sorting arrow icon is still not visible

Comment: I also tried to manually increase width to make more room, didn't work either